# moving images lower on website using bootstrap

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

Currently I have my website looking like this.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJ61I.jpg

Here's the html

```
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/opencv_css.css" />
  </head>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container">                 <!-- top intro part -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#/">  OPENCV 3.0.0</a>
      </div>

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="#/"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/about"><i class="fa fa-shield"></i> About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/contact"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i> Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <body ng-controller="MainController">

    <div class="row"> <!-- Dropdown menu  -->

      <div class="col-md-20">
    <div id="main">
      <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2">Filter List:</label>
        <div class="col-md-5">

          <select class="form-control"
              ng-model="template"
              ng-options="t as t for t in templates">
          </select>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
      </div>

      <input type="file" id="fileToUpload" name="fileToUpload">
      <button ng-click="add()">Upload</button>  
    </div>    

    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-md-push-2 col-sm-push-1 col-lg-push-1 col-md-8-col-sm-8 col-lg-6 text-warning">
    <div id="imagesData">    
      <img id="img1" src="" alt="" class="data-image" />
    </div>
      </div>

       <div class="col-md-push-4 col-sm-push-2 col-lg-push-2 col-md-16-col-sm-16 text-warning">
    <div id="imagesData">    
      <img id="img2" src="" alt="" class="data-image" />
    </div>
      </div>

    </div>


    <script src="js/jQuery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.14.3.min.js"></script>    
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

I was wondering how I would move image elements just a few pixels lower so that they aren't right against the upload button? And I know that the way I've placed the images in bootstrap must be completely wrong and awful. I'm still a noob to web dev so I simply looked at someone else's code and made it fit to my needs.

Comment: did you try some css? like padding or margins..? and btw: don't use an id twice on a  page (e.g. imagesData)..

Comment: `margin-top` doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a < br> (Without Space) it will break one line ;)

I saw this answer was given already, sorry

Comment: This worked as well! I already upvoted you then I upvoted someone else now I can't upvote you...so I just gave you the check mark! Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `margin` to your .data-image class

```
.data-image {
   margin: 10px 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well theres a few ways you could do this firstly (kinda cheaty) just use simple `<br>` tags like so...

```
<br><br>  <--- right here


<div class="row">

      <div class="col-md-push-2 col-sm-push-1 col-lg-push-1 col-md-8-col-sm-8 col-lg-6 text-warning">
    <div id="imagesData">    
      <img id="img1" src="" alt="" class="data-image" />
    </div>
      </div>

       <div class="col-md-push-4 col-sm-push-2 col-lg-push-2 col-md-16-col-sm-16 text-warning">
    <div id="imagesData">    
      <img id="img2" src="" alt="" class="data-image" />
    </div>
      </div>

    </div>
```

you can add it in before or after the row tag i think but try this